# SBT. Modify project libraryDependencies depending on custom Configuration

Tags: scala, sbt

I want compile and test my project with different libraryDependencies, on per configuration basis 
I.e. 
if i run `partial:compile` task, there should be one set of dependencies
and if run just `compile` or `test`, another set..

I've tried to use `inConfig` like in simplified listing below, but it does not seem to do the trick, because dependencies from `fullDeptsSettings` are still there. It could be seen in `inspect partial:libraryDependencies`

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.{Build, Defaults, _}

object DummyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val PartialConfig = config("partial") extend Compile

  val fullDepts = Seq (
    "my" % "customLib" % "1.0",
    "my" % "anotherLib" % "1.0"
    )

  val partialDepts = Seq("my" % "anotherLib" % "1.0")

  private val defaultSettings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings
  private val partialDeptsSettings = libraryDependencies ++= partialDepts
  private val fullDeptsSettings = libraryDependencies += fullDepts

  lazy val api = Project("dummy", file("."))
                 .configs(PartialConfig)
                 .settings(defaultSettings: _*)
                 .settings(fullDeptsSettings)
                 .settings(inConfig(PartialConfig)(partialDeptsSettings):_*)
}
```

Comment: Any reason you want to use configurations and not just sub projects? The latter sounds much easier for me in handling different dependencies. Otherwise, I think you need to understand your configuration as something similar to `% "test"`. That is, perhaps you just need to scope your dependencies with an additional configuration qualifier.

Comment: There is a reason actually. I have rather big project with about 10 sub modules in it. Those modules are classpath dependencies for root project i.e. they are listed in `dependsOn`. 
Now I want to build those modules as independent artifacts and put them in libraryDependencies. It would reduce compilation time and improve reusability of code components. The new schema would do for most of the time. Unfortunately sometimes I would want to build my project the old way i.e. with submodules in `dependsOn`. In that rare cases i have to  remove artifacts from libraryDependencies somehow